# Refresh Controller disappears after changing the tableview color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I have changed a UITableView background color and the Refresh controller disappears.

This is the code for changing the table background :

```
UIView *bview = [[UIView alloc] init];
bview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:bview];
```

[image]

Here is when I pull to refresh

[image]

```
 // Initialize the refresh control.
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(retrieveData)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

Comment: Does it work if, instead of adding a backgroundView, you just set the background color of the table view (self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];)?

Comment: no it's not http://ya-techno.com/up//uploads/images/yaTechno-e02587d55e.png

Comment: What's not working? I see the refresh control in your last link.

Comment: @rdelmar yes but the tableview color is white not black

Comment: @rdelmar the cell are black but the table in white color.

Comment: I dont' see the code self.refreshControl was added into UITableView?

Comment: @NhuNguyen     do you mean this code     [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I found is to change the scrollView appearance

```
[[UIScrollView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the background view property, just do like this.

```
// Set table view background color
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// Initialize the refresh control
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(retrieveData)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still got the white table I don't know why       http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1427596788141.png

Comment: are you sure you not setting the color somewhere else? you ca try a search  in the whole project with "whiteColor", it will show also results from nib/storyboard.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that I haven't done that. Except the cell color